# laravel 5 - Select all columns without asterix when joining tables with eloquent or query builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-5.1

Is there any built-in laravel functions via which we can select all the fields of a database table without manually typing in all the fields using the select() method.

I know we can achieve the same using the get() method , but it generates the query in the form SELECT *

I don't want a SELECT * instead SELECT all_fields auto-magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **Schema::getColumnListing**

```
Model::select([DB::raw(join(', ',Schema::getColumnListing('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')))])
```